# ksar show only one day from monthly sar report in OpenSuse

Tags: performance, graph, report, opensuse, sar

I try to graph performance by ksar. In my CentOs machines I do the following:

```
for i in /var/log/sa/sa??; do sar --legacy -A -f $i >>monthly; done
ksar -input 'file:////root/monthly'
```

That show me all the 30 days -- but, in OpenSuse ksar show me only one day.

Here some experiences I try with no success:

```
for i in /var/log/sa/sa??; do sar -A -f $i >>monthly; done
```

or

```
cat /var/log/sa/sar?? >> monthly
```

or

```
scp root@aCentosMachine:monthly  .
```

Any idea? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is bad.

From wikipadia   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ksar_%28Unix_sar_grapher%29

> Known issues
>
> Sometime due to unknown reason multiple day graphs are not being
>   generated.

So it is a bug and I am luck that I can do multiple day on Centos